# exporting mysql table with bulk data in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I have a mysql table with large amount of data. I need to export this table to another database with all the data. But when I try to export the table as sql file from phpmyadmin, it shows error 
`The webpage at https://i.p.adress/domains/databases/phpMyAdmin/export.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.`
I tried exporting as CSV also, but the same error happens.
Does it happens because my table contains large amount of data? Is there any other way to export this table with all data?

I have around 1346641 records.

Answer (score 0):

Does export work with a smaller database? Does it process for some time before showing that error or is it displayed as soon as you confirm your export options? I don't recall having seen that error message relating to large exports, but I may be remembering incorrectly. Any hints in your webserver or PHP error logs? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Regarding large exports:

Because of the nature of phpMyAdmin running as a PHP script on your server, as well as sending the downloaded file to you as a download, there are a number of limitations forced on it. Web servers are usually configured to keep PHP programs from running for very long, and a long download (or long time processing the export) can be affected. Additionally, memory and other resources are often limited in a similar manner. Therefore, it's usually better to use some other means of exporting large databases.

The command-line utility `mysqldump`, provided with the MySQL server package, is the definitive standard. If you have command line/shell access, it's best to use mysqldump to export the .sql file(s) and then copy those through any normal file-transfer protocol (FTP, SCP, SSH, etc).

That being said, phpMyAdmin has several enhancements and tweaks that can make this possible.

- Use `$cfg[SaveDir]` to enable [writing the exported file to disk on the server](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_SaveDir), which you can then copy through any normal file transfer protocol.
- If you encounter timeouts or resource restrictions, you can [edit the PHP configuration directives](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems) (the linked documentation refers to imports but the same restrictions apply to exports).
- Experiment with the export compression setting, in particular using an uncompressed export format (exporting to SQL directly rather than a zipped archive) can work around some memory restrictions.